# My program can't run that fast even with memoization

Tags: python, fibonacci

I tried a problem on project euler where I needed to find the sum of all the fibonacci terms under 4 million. It took me a long time but then I found out that I can use memoization to do it but it seems to take still a long time. After a lot of research, I found out that I can use a built-in module called lru_cache. My question is : why isn't it as fast as memoization ?

Here's my code:

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=1000000)
def fibonacci_memo(input_value):
    global value
    fibonacci_cache = {}
    if input_value in fibonacci_cache:
        return fibonacci_cache[input_value]
    if input_value == 0:
        value = 1
    elif input_value == 1:
        value = 1
    elif input_value > 1:
        value = fibonacci_memo(input_value - 1) + fibonacci_memo(input_value - 2)
        fibonacci_cache[input_value] = value
    return value


def sumOfFib():
    SUM = 0
    for n in range(500):
        if fibonacci_memo(n) < 4000000:
            if fibonacci_memo(n) % 2 == 0:
                SUM += fibonacci_memo(n)
    return SUM


print(sumOfFib())
```

The code works by the way. It takes less than a second to run it when I use the lru_cache module.

Comment: The sum satisfies a linear recurrence relation of constant order. Find it and compute the sum directly.

Comment: The problem can be solved in effectively O(n) by keeping the current sum, and the last 2 fibonacci values in memory in a loop until you reach a number higher than 4 billion.

Comment: Further more, if you express the recurrence as a matrix multiplication, then you can solve it in O(ln(n)).

Comment: _It took me a long time but then I found out that I can use memoization to do it but it seems to take still a long time. After a lot of research, I found out that I can use a built-in module called lru_cache. My question is : why isn't it as fast as memoization ?_ Isn't using `lru_cache` memoization? I'm not sure I understand how the two are related in the code you shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is the correct way to calculate the fibonacci sequence, indeed, but you should also know why your memoization wasn't working. To be specific:

`fibonacci_cache = {}`

This line being inside the function means you were emptying your cache every time fibonacci_memo was called.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be computing the Fibonacci sequence, not even by dynamic programming. Since the Fibonacci sequence satisfies a linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients and constant order, then so will be the sequence of their sums.

Definitely don't cache all the values. That will give you an unnecessary consumption of memory. When the recurrences have constant order, you only need to remember as many previous terms as the order of the recurrence.

Further more, there is a way to turn recurrences of constant order into systems recurrences of order one. The solution of the latter is given by a power of a matrix. This gives a faster algorithm, for large values of `n`. Each step will be more expensive, though. So, the best method would use a combination of the two, choosing the first method for small values of `n` and the latter for large inputs.

**O(n) using the recurrence for the sum**

Denote `S_n=F_0+F_1+...+F_n` the sum of the first Fibonacci numbers `F_0,F_1,...,F_n`.

Observe that

- `S_{n+1}-S_n=F_{n+1}`
- `S_{n+2}-S_{n+1}=F_{n+2}`
- `S_{n+3}-S_{n+2}=F_{n+3}`

Since `F_{n+3}=F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}` we get that `S_{n+3}-S_{n+2}=S_{n+2}-S_n`. So

`S_{n+3}=2S_{n+2}-S_n`

with the initial conditions `S_0=F_0=1`, `S_1=F_0+F_1=1+1=2`, and `S_2=S_1+F_2=2+2=4`.

One thing that you can do is compute `S_n` bottom up, remembering the values of only the previous three terms at each step. You don't need to remember all of the values of `S_k`, from `k=0` to `k=n`. This gives you an `O(n)` algorithm with `O(1)` amount of memory.

---

**O(ln(n)) by matrix exponentiation**

You can also get an `O(ln(n))` algorithm in the following way:

Call `X_n` to be the column vector with components `S_{n+2},S_{n+1},S_{n}`

So, the recurrence above gives the recurrence

`X_{n+1}=AX_n`

where `A` is the matrix

```
[
 [2,0,-1],
 [1,0,0],
 [0,1,0],
]
```

Therefore, `X_n=A^nX_0`. We have `X_0`. To multiply by `A^n` we can do [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: All true, but not really relevant to the OP's progrramming question. There is no way that the thing should take anywhere near one second.

Comment: @IgorRivin It doesn't point out the actual bug in OP's code, true. Still, I don't see any harm in showing "the right way" of doing this.

Comment: By the way, the matrix way of doing this, though cute and clever is not actually as good as you think it is. If you use naive multiplication (vs FFT) it buys you a constant factor over the dumb method.

Comment: @IgorRivin Sorry, I don't quite follow. Could you explain how FFT comes in here?

Comment: @PaulPanzer When the numbers become large it becomes important to perform the multiplication efficiently. You can think of multiplying numbers as multiplying polynomials evaluated at the base `10`, or `2`, which ever you use, for example. Then you can use FFT. Theoretically, there are now [asymptotically better methods](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document).

Comment: @PaulPanzer for simplicity, think of computing N**1024, Repeated squaring is 10 ops, iterative 1023. Much worse, right? Wrong! the nth  multiplication in the iterative algorithm takes time `c n`, for a total of `cn^2/2 `bit complexity. The ith repeated squaring takes time proportional to to 2^(2i). So, in the end you still have O(n^2) algorithm. Matrices are the same. But if you use fast multiplication (say, FFT) then you actually do win.

Comment: Thanks NotDijksta,@IgorRivin. So what you are saying is multiplication of ints in some base is essentially a convolution, hence FFT. Do you use fixed precision numbers for that? Or how do you calculate the cost of non integer operations? And, back to Fibonacci and friends, once we have ditched integerness, is there any chance, the closed form solution (linear combination of geometric sequences) might be competitive?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, Clifford Stein - *Introduction to algorithms* has a nice explanation. I am not sure where do you mean fixed precision numbers. Do you mean in the point-wise multiplication step? One would keep on doing fast multiplication if the values are large. Anyway, all of that is pretty irrelevant to this question. The closed form solution, if properly implemented gives a number of steps in the same `O` class. However, it has the ugliness of having to compute the roots of the characteristic polynomial to high precision.

Comment: @NotDijkstra Thank you for your time and expertise. One last remark: Once you've fixed an oversight in your first recurrence which must be `S_{n+1} = S_n+F_{n+1}` it is easy to verify `S_n = F_{n+2}-F_1` i.e. it's just an (x and y) shifted Fibonacci, which should simplify things considerably.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, the was a wrong subscript at the beginning. Your expression in terms of Fibonacci can also be used. It yields essentially the same algorithms. The same ideas apply.

Comment: @NotDijkstra yep, but with a 2x2 matrix instead of a 3x3.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness here are implementations of the general ideas described in @NotDijkstra's answer plus my humble optimizations including the "closed form" solution implemented in integer arithmetic.

We can see that the "smart" methods are not only an order of magnitude faster but also seem to scale better compatible with the fact (thanks @NotDijkstra) that Python big ints use better than naive multiplication.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import operator as op
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
B = BenchmarkBuilder()

def pow(b,e,mul=op.mul,unit=1):
    if e == 0:
        return unit
    res = b
    for bit in bin(e)[3:]:
        res = mul(res,res)
        if bit=="1":
            res = mul(res,b)
    return res

def mul_fib(a,b):
    return (a[0]*b[0]+5*a[1]*b[1])>>1 , (a[0]*b[1]+a[1]*b[0])>>1

def fib_closed(n):
    return pow((1,1),n+1,mul_fib)[1]

def fib_mat(n):
    return pow(np.array([[1,1],[1,0]],'O'),n,op.matmul)[0,0]

def fib_sequential(n):
    t1,t2 = 1,1
    for i in range(n-1):
        t1,t2 = t2,t1+t2
    return t2

def sum_fib_direct(n):
    t1,t2,res = 1,1,1
    for i in range(n):
        t1,t2,res = t2,t1+t2,res+t2
    return res
    
def sum_fib(n,method="closed"):
    if method == "direct":
        return sum_fib_direct(n)
    return globals()[f"fib_{method}"](n+2)-1

methods = "closed mat sequential direct".split()

def f(method):
    def f(n):
        return sum_fib(n,method)
    f.__name__ = method
    return f

for method in methods:
    B.add_function(method)(f(method))

B.add_arguments('N')(lambda:(2*(1<<k,) for k in range(23)))

r = B.run()
r.plot()

import matplotlib.pylab as P
P.savefig(fib.png)
```

Comment: The claim that they made that those methods only give a constant factor optimization is wrong. They were just clinking to the assumption of doing integer multiplication the naive way. Python multiplies large integers using Karatsuba's algorithm. So, even theoretically that claim is false. Practically, for this range of numbers `n=10000` you have around `14` multiplications (numbers or matrices) only and the largest number has only 2K digits. Probably even with naive multiplication these methods do better than the 'direct' method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are taking anything near a second. Here is the memoized version without fanciness:

```
class fibs(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thefibs = {0:0, 1:1}

    def __call__(self, n):
        if n not in self.thefibs:
            self.thefibs[n] = self(n-1)+self(n-2)
        return self.thefibs[n]

dog = fibs()

sum([dog(i) for i in range(40) if dog(i) < 4000000])
```

Comment: I don't know how to use classes for these types of problem but I will definitely look into that.